# dtype={'col_name":str} doesn't convert to strings

Tags: python, pandas, dtype

I have problems converting int into str when creating a dict from two columns in an excel_file.

```
fields = ['size','size_webshop']
    
dct_of_sizes =pd.read_excel('path.xlsx', usecols=fields, index_col=0, squeeze=True, dtype={'size':str, 'size_webshop': str}).to_dict()
dct_of_sizes
```

results in

```
{'XS': 'XS',
 'S ': 'S ',
 'M': 'M',
 'L': 'L',
 'XL': 'XL',
 'XXL': 'XXL',
 'XS/S': 'XS/S',
 'S/M': 'S/M',
 'M/L': 'M/L',
 'L/XL': 'L/XL',
 'XL/XXL': 'XL/XXL',
 363: '36/38',
 404: '40/42',
 444: '44/46',
 485: '48/50',
 525: '52/54',
 36: '36',
 38: '38',
 40: '40',
 42: '42',
 44: '44',
 46: '46',
 48: '48',
 50: '50',
 52: '52',
 54: '54',
 56: '56',
 58: '58'}
```

in the first column the sizes 363-58 are read as int and didn't convert to str. In the second column these sizes did convert.  ??

Comment: try `'size':'string'` instead of `'size':str`

Comment: works perfect. but why?